# How to cancel DelayedConfirmationView?

Tags: android, wear-os

As per standard Android Wear UI, I'm trying to cancel the confirmation animation on a `DelayedConfirmationView` when the user taps on it again before the timer is complete. However, there's only a `start()` method provided, as reflected in the API reference (downloadable [here](https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/wearable-support-docs.zip)).

I've attempted a workaround by setting `setTotalTimeMs()` to 0 upon cancellation, which completes the animation immediately - but the full circle border is now displayed for eternity! There's no `setCircleBorderWidth()` method through which I might be able to reduce the border to 0, even though there's a corresponding xml declaration of `app:circle_border_width`. The `setProgress()` method in the CircleImageView superclass doesn't seem to do anything either.

Has anyone found a way to cancel the confirmation animation directly, or at least a workaround that sets the button to its original state (no border)?

Comment: Do you want to cancel the timer OR just want to hide the border & wants to have simple Button like layout?

Comment: Both. I want to cancel the countdown, and also provide UI feedback to the user that the countdown has been cancelled by reverting the DelayedConfirmationView to its original state (i.e. resetting the border.)

Comment: Any luck in figuring this out?

Comment: Nope. I ended up just using the workaround of setTotalTimeMs(0) for countdown interruptions - not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness (although partial, because the circle around the button still sticks until you re-inflate the view), I am posting the code that I had to use to stop the counter **without triggering the action**.

```
@Override
public void onTimerSelected(View view) {
    if(mRunning) {
        mRunning = false;
        delayedConfirmationView.setTotalTimeMs(0);
    } else {
        view.setPressed(true);
        mRunning = true;
        delayedConfirmationView.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTimerFinished(View view) {
    view.setPressed(false);
    if (mRunning) {
        mRunning = false;
        performAction();
    } else {
        delayedConfirmationView.setTotalTimeMs(CONFIRMATION_TIME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DelayedConfirmationView.reset()` does the job.

You just need to keep track of the running state like cowst did in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google in their sample just use

> mDelayedView.setListener(null);

```
private DelayedConfirmationView mDelayedView;
...
mDelayedView = (DelayedConfirmationView) stub.findViewById(R.id.act_main__delayed_confirm);
...
private DelayedConfirmationView.DelayedConfirmationListener mDelayedViewListener =  new DelayedConfirmationView.DelayedConfirmationListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTimerFinished(View view)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onTimerFinished() : Time out launching reboot");

        // User did not cancel, let's go
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimerSelected(View parView)
    {
        // User canceled, abort the action

        // Prevent onTimerFinished from being heard.
        mDelayedView.setListener(null);
        ...
    }
};
```